# How to convert Hindu-Arabic numerals to Bengali numerals in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, locale

I made a method `serial_bn`, which takes a Hindu-Arabic numeral and returns the corresponding Bengali numeral:

```
def serial_bn(var)
    if var == "1"
      return "১"
    end
    if var == "2"
      return "২"
    end
    if var == "3"
       return "৩"
    end
    if var == "4"
       return "৪"
    end
    if var == "5"
       return "৫"
    end
    if var == "6"
       return "৬"
    end
    if var == "7"
       return "৭"
    end
    if var == "8"
       return "৮"
    end
    if var == "9"
       return "৯"
    end
    if var == "0"  
       return "০"
    end
  end
```

I want to pass each digit of a number as a string to the above method. For example, for `"1234"`, I want the output to be like `"১২৩৪"` without a space in between.

I tried:

```
"1234".to_s.split('').each do |i|
 serial_bn(i.chr)
```

which returns an output with a white space in between:

```
"১ ২ ৩ ৪"
```

Any help?

Comment: Your example code is invalid: the closing `end` is missing and I don't see how it could return the given output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings have a `tr` method, which replaces characters:

```
p "123409".tr( "1234567890", "১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯০") # => "১২৩৪০৯"
```

Comment: [a bit late to the party](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42974545/1772830) :)

Comment: Please transfer the "accept"to sawa's answer - it is identical to this, but he was faster.  Is this certain language Bengali?

Answer (score 8):

```
"1234".tr("1234567890", "১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯০")
# => "১২৩৪"
```

or, I am not sure about the target language, but probably this should work as well:

```
"1234".tr("0-9", "০-৯")
# => "১২৩৪"
```

Comment: nice, very nice, +1

Comment: damn, beat me to it :)

Comment: If you want to confuse the reader : `"1234".gsub(/\d/){|x|(x.ord+2486).chr('UTF-8')}`

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest you somewhat more "conventional" approach to the problem.

Since mapping is stable, create a constant:

```
SERIAL_BN_MAP = {
  1 => '১',
  2 => '২',
  3 => '৩',
  4 => '৪',
  5 => '৫',
  6 => '৬',
  7 => '৭',
  8 => '৮',
  9 => '৯',
  0 => '০'
}.freeze
```

Now method (using [Integer#`digits`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits)):

```
def convert(number)
  number.digits.reverse.map { |d| SERIAL_BN_MAP[d] }.join
end
```

Usage:

```
convert(1234)
#=> "১২৩৪"
```

Comment: If your hash has only values between 0 and n-1, you could just use an Array (e.g. `("০".."৯").to_a`) or a String (`"০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯"`)

Comment: @EricDuminil I wrote the answer without any assumption about sequentiality of hash values. To me these are just hieroglyphs :)

Comment: Shoot, I meant keys. keys are sequential!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `gsub`

```
2.2.5 :011 > text = "১ ২ ৩ ৪"
2.2.5 :010 > text.gsub(' ','')
 => "১২৩৪"
```

Also, I'd suggest you use a case statement -

```
def serial_bn(var)
  case var
  when "1" then "১" 
  when "2" then "২"
  # etc
  else
    # handle other input
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine Andrey and sawas answers, as both have good implementation within some sort of language specific conversion class:

```
SERIAL_CONVERSION = "১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯০"
EN_SERIAL_DIGITS = "1234567890"

( ... )

def convert_serial(serial)
  serial.tr(EN_SERIAL_DIGITS, SERIAL_CONVERSION)
end
```

You could have a fancier way of mapping EN digits with the other language, perhaps even have the class inheriting from an EnglishDigit class or something, so that you don't need to duplicate EN_SERIAL_DIGITS. Up to you really, but I'd always use some sort of constant here.